# Bitrix 24 CRM, como desarrollar?

Tags: crm

Tengo algunas preguntas para alguien que ha trabajado con **Bitrix 24 framework**, resulta que la empresa en donde estoy trabajando han comprado dicho sistema y quiero agregar algunos campos dependientes (select o combobox) **donde la persona pueda escoger x distrito y otro campo select de Barrio sea llenado automáticamente con los barrios que pertenecen a el distrito seleccionado**, he estado leyendo el manual de bitrix pero son muy básicos y no explican bien como desarrollar o agregar scripts

El manual esta [aquí](https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=68&LESSON_ID=6149&LESSON_PATH=5936.6148.6149), por si alguien lo quiere mirar (pero advierto que son muy básicos)

He adjuntado una imagen para explicar mejor

Gracias de antemano!, agradeceré cualquier ayuda...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Carlos tu empresa que version de bitrix compro selfhosted u oncloud.
debes de ingresar a los modulos de bitrix por consola y buscar ese campo.

Ingresa como administrador a tu pagina de bitrix y activa la opcion de modo edicion, para que te indique la ruta donde debes modificar.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, uso la versión selfhosted, y como entraría por consola? hay algún manual para ello?, tampoco he visto la opción de "modo edición" en el admin de bitrix

Comment: Para poder ingresar por ssh a tu servidor.

Comment: no hay una guia, pero tambien puedes utilizar listas para que puedas llamar toda la informacion que necesitas al crm.